# Enabling the OpenSSL in XAMPP

Tags: php, ssl, xampp

I spent three hours but I did not find anything; I'm unable to connect to a SSL enabled server. I want to list what i did:

First checked my PHP extensions directory was in order; extension wasn't there, **php_openssl.dll**

Then I opened my **php.ini** file but I could not see any **extension=php_openssl.dll** line to uncomment.

Also, I searched on Google and saw people with the same problem. 
http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=162623

However, I also have

```
OPENSSL_CONF C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf 
...
openssl
OpenSSL support enabled 
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009 
OpenSSL Header Version OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
```

no lines . What should I do? Please share your suggestions.

Answer (score 110):

Yes, you must open `php.ini` and remove the semicolon to:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

If you don't have that line, check that you have the file (In my PC is on `D:\xampp\php\ext`) and add this to `php.ini` in the "Dynamic Extensions" section:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: You might also need to uncomment 'extension_dir = "ext"' in php.ini and set the path accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the comment right above.  I guess I had changed it at some point for something... I guess.  Anyways, thanks.

Comment: The php.ini file is usually in xampp/php/php.ini

Answer (score 9):

```
[PHP_OPENSSL]
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

This is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Things have changed for PHP > 7. This is what i had to do for PHP 7.2.

**Step: 1:** Uncomment `extension=openssl`

**Step: 2:** Uncomment `extension_dir = "ext"`

**Step: 3:** Restart xampp.

**Done.**

**Explanation: ( From php.ini )**

If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following syntax:

```
extension=modulename
```

**Note :** The syntax used in previous PHP versions (`extension=<ext>.so` and `extension='php_<ext>.dll`) is supported for legacy reasons and may be deprecated in a future PHP major version. So, when it is possible, please move to the new (`extension=<ext>`) syntax.

**Special Note:** Be sure to appropriately set the `extension_dir` directive.

Answer (score 3):

So, what did we do to make `openssl_pkey_new()` and all the other `openssl_` functions in PHP work...

- Enabled the extension `php_openssl.dll` in the (right/active) `php.ini`. Checked.
- Checked that there exists a `openssl.cnf` in `xampp\apache\conf\` (and also in two other directories within XAMPP). Checked.
- Added the environment variable `OPENSSL_CONF` in the Windows system settings with the full path to the above `openssl.cnf`. Checked.
- Restarted Apache (and after that did not work restarted the computer several times...). Checked.

Still does not work, and throwing errors such as

- error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
- error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory
- error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file

---

Okay, here are another two more things to check.

**1. Trouble with the environment**

Run `phpinfo()` from a PHP script, and go to the "Apache Environment" section. Check the value of `OPENSSL_CONF`.

Surprise. This is not what we have set in the windows system settings.

The solution is simple. Set the environment variable in the PHP script.

```
putenv('OPENSSL_CONF=C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf');
```

**2. Trouble with relative filenames**

Now, `openssl_pkey_new()` will work, but `openssl_pkey_export_to_file()` does still not work and returns `false` without any further explanation?

Check the filename that you have specified as output filename. It will not work in Windows as long as you do not specify the full path.

```
$folder = realpath('../keyring');
$outfile = $folder.'/private.pem';
openssl_pkey_export_to_file($key, $outfile);
```

Comment: It is not `php_info()`, but `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Just add this line to the Apache httpd.conf file. 
`SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF  C:/xampp/apache/conf/openssl.cnf `

Answer (score 2):

I use xampp. Beforehand I tried the example file "test_smtp_gmail_basic.php" in phpMailer (you can download phpMailer here: https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer), but I got the following error:

Mailer Error: The following From address failed: xxx@gmail.com

After I commented out `; extension=php_openssl.dll` in php.ini, it is working now.

Answer (score 2):

In xampp, if "extension=php_openssl.dll" is not present in your php.ini file then add it in the "Windows Extensions" section of your php.ini file 
and restart your apache.
It works for me..

Answer (score 1):

You will need to edit your php.ini. It's 4 easy steps.

Find your php.ini file.

```
$inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();
```

Enable openssl in the file:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Turn allow_url_fopen on

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

Restart apache and you are done!

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1: On your `php.ini` comment out `;extension=php_openssl.dll`

STEP 2: Copy libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll from your PHP root folder and paste it your Apache/bin folder

STEP 3: Restart Apache

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that this question is for those using a windows based system.

After making sure that the extension extension=php_openssl.dll in your php.ini file does not have a semicolon.

Then make sure that you have added C:/xampp/apache/bin into your environment path in order to use openssl without having move the command prompt to that directory C:/xampp/apache/bin

Answer (score 0):

Although not related to this question but as the WP migrate Pro docs link to this question I though I would post an answer here.

If your having problems with DB Migrate Pro activating instead of enabling SSL you can just add a line of code to your wp-config

`define( 'WPMDB_LICENCE', 'XXXXXXXXXXx' );`