# Call to undefined function openssl_pkcs7_sign()

Tags: php, ssl, digital-signature, tcpdf, digital-certificate

I'm using TCPDF to sign son PFD documents.
I was testing the examples via web: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php, and they worked fine, but when I downloaded the lib and tested it  @ localhost I got this error in "example 52":

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function openssl_pkcs7_sign() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebas\pdf_firma\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 9043

My PHP is Version 5.3.8.

Any has any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Openssl must be installed

[Enabling the OpenSSL in XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466086/enabling-the-openssl-in-xampp)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.setup.php