# Composer and mamp ssl extension not working together

Tags: symfony, ssl, mamp, composer-php

I was trying to enable ssl extension on MAMP to get a sylius (symfony2 bundle) working. But when the extension was enabled, composer started to misbehave saying that the ssl extension wasn't installed...

I follow this tutorial to install ssl extension:
http://soundsplausible.com/2012/01/14/enable-ssl-in-mamp-2-0-5/

Before following the tutorial, my composer was working fine. Now, I'm getting this error:

```
Some settings on your machine may cause stability issues with Composer.

=======================================
If you encounter issues, try to change the following:
=======================================
The openssl extension is missing, which will reduce the security and stability of Composer.
=======================================
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl
======================================
```

I tried to cancel the installation of ssl that I've done but it's not working.

Comment: Is composer wrong? Or is your ssl extension actually not working? Check `phpinfo()` for more information.

Comment: I would say it's the ssl extension that is not working. Before I mess with the extension, composer was working fine. But since I tried to install the extension (following the tutorial http://soundsplausible.com/2012/01/14/enable-ssl-in-mamp-2-0-5/) composer is not working any more.

Comment: What does `phpinfo()` say? is the extension loaded? You can test it with this command: `$ php -info| grep openssl`

Comment: OpenSSL support => disabled (install ext/openssl)

Comment: [Enable it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466086/enabling-the-openssl-in-xampp) then :)

Comment: I have the same issue on my Mac ML since 2 days trying to use Composer.  

openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013  

which openssl
/opt/local/bin/openssl  

phpinfo say
Phar - Native OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL support enabled  

But still:
php -info| grep openssl
OpenSSL support => disabled (install ext/openssl)  

And more annoying when i run composer it says:  
    [RuntimeException]                                                 
    You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https

How do you enable something that system says it is already enable.:D

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the file from given url to the current directory of the php bin folder:

`copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer','c:\mamp\bin\php\php5.6.8\composer.phar');`

and it worked.