# enable php_openssl not working

Tags: php, apache, xampp, php-openssl

Im trying to enable php_openssl but its not working,

i kinda have the same problem as this question
[Enabling the OpenSSL in XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466086/enabling-the-openssl-in-xampp)

in my php.ini
there is no extension
extension=php_openssl.dll

but there was this 
OPENSSL_CONF C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf

so i added the extension=php_openssl.dll to my php.ini
but when i add , i checked my xampp\php\ext and there was no php_openssl.dll file,

so i googled for the module, then i put it in my xampp\php\ext
restart apache, but still getting error - specified module could not be found

my current version is
xampp 1.7.3
php 5.3.1

if can provide the download link of the module, or guide...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to activate it my last resort is use different xampp, ver 1.7.7 works for me just activate the following extension in your in php.ini

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```