# Send email in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am newbie in CodeIgniter. May I know how to send an email in CodeIgniter via localhost? What should I put in the `smtp_user` and `smtp_pass`? Below is my controller code:

```
function Forgot_Password()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|callback_email_check');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('Forgot_Password');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer'); 
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->library('email');


           $config = Array(
               'protocol' => 'smtp',
               'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
               'smtp_port' => 465,
               'smtp_user' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
               'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxxxxx'
               );

            $this->load->library('email', $config);
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            $this->email->from('26328@siswa.unimas.my', 'Your Name');
            $this->email->to('foo.900.fch@gmail.com'); 
            //$this->email->cc('another@another-example.com'); 
            //$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com'); 

            $this->email->subject('Email Test');
            $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  

            if($this->email->send())
            {
                echo 'Email sent.';
            }
            else
            {
                show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
            }
        }
     }
```

In config.php (config folder), I have:

```
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'; // SMTP Server Address.
$config['smtp_port'] = '465'; // SMTP Port.
$config['protocol'] ='sendmail';
```

Comment: Any errors in particular?

Comment: Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
I dont know what should i put for the smtp_user and smtp_pass.

Comment: Are you using localhost?

Comment: yup.i want to send an email to a existing account.

Comment: You must install a mail server.

Comment: how to install it?i using window 7.

Answer (score 3):

You have to configure sendmail in your system.

If you are using ubuntu follow the steps: 
If you want to use a Gmail account as a free SMTP server on your Ubuntu-Linux server, you will find this article useful. This guide is tested with Ubuntu 12.04. If you face any issue, feel free to use comments-section below.
Relaying Postfix mails via smtp.gmail.com:

First, install all necessary packages:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix mailutils libsasl2-2 ca-certificates libsasl2-modules
```

If you do not have postfix installed before, postfix configuration wizard will ask you some questions. Just select your server as Internet Site and for FQDN use something like mail.example.com

Then open your postfix config file:

```
vim /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

and following lines to it:

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_use_tls = yes
```

You might have noticed that we haven’t specified our Gmail username and password in above lines. They will go into a different file. Open/Create

```
vim /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

And add following line:

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587    USERNAME@gmail.com:PASSWORD
```

If you want to use your Google App’s domain, please replace @gmail.com with your @domain.com

Fix permission and update postfix config to use sasl_passwd file:

```
sudo chmod 400 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

Next, validate certificates to avoid running into error. Just run following command:

```
cat /etc/ssl/certs/Thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem | sudo tee -a /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
```

Finally, reload postfix config for changes to take effect:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix reload
```

Testing
Check if mails are sent via Gmail SMTP server

If you have configured everything correctly, following command should generate a test mail from your server to your mailbox.

```
echo "Test mail from postfix" | mail -s "Test Postfix" you@example.com
```

For more details : https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/

Thanks to rtcamp.com, It helped me a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Google mail required `ssl` for `SMTP` auth so `open_ssl` should be enable extension in your `php.ini`

Codeigniter mail library more details about SSL/TLS [click here](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/2320)

Enable OPEN SSL in php 
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466086/enabling-the-openssl-in-xampp?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: ya.The semicolon has been removed but still unable to send email.

Comment: @Carson ok, did you also checked `open_ssl` extension on your server?

Comment: how to check open_ssl extension on my server?

Comment: @Carson , i have added answer another link in answer, check your `php.ini` file

Comment: ya,checked and enable the open_ssl but still unable to send.