# Composer download error. extension=php_openssl.dll not found in php.ini

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php

I tried to install composer with the composer installer and I got this error "Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl
"

I googled it and I realised I have to enable openssl in my php.ini file, I have to remove the semi-colon in front of this line ;extension=php_openssl.dll. The problem is that that line is not present in my php.ini file but it is present in my php.ini-development and php.ini-production files. I already edited the line in the two files but composer is still not installing. How do I get composer to install? Should I add the line to php.ini or what? I use xampp btw.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling the openssl in xampp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466086/enabling-the-openssl-in-xampp)

Comment: OK, I checked out that thread and I added "extension=php_openssl.dll" to the "windows extension" section of php.ini, restarted apache and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Please try adding that line to your php.ini file and it should solve it.