# eWay Responsive Shared Page integration in PHP by Using CURL

Tags: php, curl, payment

I am trying to integrate eWay payment gateway (Responsive Shared Page) by using Curl(json) in php.it is working fine in my virtual machine that is ubuntu12.0
but curl not getting any response if i exceute same code on xampp server.
What is problem with curl?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29298825/edit) to include [appropriate tags](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) (such as [tag:php]) and a [small example of your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

While it would be helpful if you could at least provide the error you are getting (details for [finding the error log are here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-phps-error-log-reside-in-xampp)), most XAMPP issues are because it either doesn't have openssl enabled or it isn't loading the CA bundle to verify SSLs with. The solutions can be found in the following:

- [Enable OpenSSL with XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466086/enabling-the-openssl-in-xampp)
- [Adding the CA bundle to XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/https-and-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed-ca-is-ok)