# Php mailer doesn't working

Tags: php, email, openssl, phpmailer

I use Xampp, and i would like email send with phpmailer.

My error has issued:

> Extension missing: openssl
>
> Mailer Error: Extension missing: openssl

I made all settings in php.ini: `;extension=php_openssl.dll` to `extension=php_openssl.dll`

and restart apache.

What is my  problem?
Thanks!!

**---UPDATE----**

It seems to have been solved in the OpenSSL problem.
Now I get the following error message:

2018-03-15 09:24:02 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array()
2018-03-15 09:24:02 Connection: opened
2018-03-15 09:24:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2018-03-15 09:24:13 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
2018-03-15 09:24:13 Connection: closed
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Have you really installed OpenSSL or only enabled an extension that might exist or not? Does phpinfo tell you that OpenSSL is working?

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466086/enabling-the-openssl-in-xampp

Comment: In your php.ini find and change `extension_dir = "ext"` to something like this: `extension_dir = "c:/php710/ext"`

Answer (score 0):

You can send mail from localhost with sendmail package , sendmail package is inbuild in XAMPP. So if you are using XAMPP then you can easily send mail from localhost.

for example you can configure C:\xampp\php\php.ini and c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini for gmail to send mail.

in C:\xampp\php\php.ini find extension=php_openssl.dll and remove the semicolon from the beginning of that line to make SSL working for gmail for localhost.

in php.ini file find [mail function] and change

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = my-gmail-id@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

Now Open C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini. Replace all the existing code in sendmail.ini with following code

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
auth_password=my-gmail-password
force_sender=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
Now you have done!! create php file with mail function and send mail from localhost.
```

PS: don't forgot to replace my-gmail-id and my-gmail-password in above code. Also, don't forget to remove duplicate keys if you copied settings from above. For example comment following line if there is another sendmail_path : sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe" in the php.ini file

Also remember to restart the server using the XAMMP control panel so the changes take effect.

For gmail please check https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255 to allow access from less secure apps.

Comment: This may be true, but it has nothing to do with sending email using SSL with PHPMailer, which is what the question is about.